# ImageButton touch feedback

Tags: imagebutton, touch-feedback

how can I implement a touch feedback for ImageButtons? I want the image button to change the image when the button is touched. I already searched, but after trying some things that didn't worked I'm  a bit desperate. Is a selector the right thing for this problem and how does this work?

My current try is to create a new .xml file in the drawable folder. There I would put a selector, this is my current code for the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/testbuttonimageselected" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/testbuttonimage" />
</selector>
```

And this is my current code for the .java file:

```
btnTest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View button) {
       //Set the button's appearance
       button.setSelected(!button.isSelected());

        if (button.isSelected()) {
           //Handle selected state change
        } else {
           //Handle de-select state change
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using a state list, and assigning a different image to each state:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm trying right now, but it doesn't work. I added the code to my question. Maybe you can spot a mistake?

Comment: You need to set the StateListDrawable as the drawable of your ImageButton. You do not need to handle the states yourself.